# code sending out duplicate alerts on question evaluation

Tags: javascript, alert

i'm creating a quiz game in javascript, and I'm using alerts to send out to the user whether or not the question is right or not. However, the code sends out duplicate alerts depending on what question the user is on (question 2 gets 2 alerts, question 3 gets 3 alerts, etc).
The code is here, and you can test it here https://quiz-game.jackpowell8.repl.co/

`

```
// Questions will be asked
const Questions = [{
        id: 0,
        q: "MYSTERY QUESTION #1",
        a: [{ text: "1", isCorrect: true },
            { text: "2", isCorrect: false },
            { text: "3", isCorrect: false },
            { text: "4", isCorrect: false }
        ]

    },
    {
        id: 1,
        q: "MYSTERY QUESTION #2",
        a: [{ text: "1", isCorrect: false},
            { text: "2", isCorrect: false },
            { text: "3", isCorrect: false },
            { text: "4", isCorrect: true }
        ]

    },
    {
        id: 2,
        q: "MYSTERY QUESTION #3",
        a: [{ text: "1", isCorrect: false },
            { text: "2", isCorrect: false },
            { text: "3", isCorrect: true },
            { text: "4", isCorrect: false }
        ]

    }

]

// Set start
var start = true;

//Define score
var score = 0
//Define attempts
var attempts = 0

// Iterate
function iterate(id) {

    // Getting the result display section
    var result = document.getElementsByClassName("result");
    result[0].innerText = "";

    // Getting the question
    const question = document.getElementById("question");


    // Setting the question text
    question.innerText = Questions[id].q;

    // Getting the options
    const op1 = document.getElementById('op1');
    const op2 = document.getElementById('op2');
    const op3 = document.getElementById('op3');
    const op4 = document.getElementById('op4');


    // Providing option text
    op1.innerText = Questions[id].a[0].text;
    op2.innerText = Questions[id].a[1].text;
    op3.innerText = Questions[id].a[2].text;
    op4.innerText = Questions[id].a[3].text;

    // Providing the true or false value to the options
    op1.value = Questions[id].a[0].isCorrect;
    op2.value = Questions[id].a[1].isCorrect;
    op3.value = Questions[id].a[2].isCorrect;
    op4.value = Questions[id].a[3].isCorrect;

    var selected = "";

    // Show selection for op1
    op1.addEventListener("click", () => {
        op1.style.backgroundColor = "lightgoldenrodyellow";
        op2.style.backgroundColor = "lightskyblue";
        op3.style.backgroundColor = "lightskyblue";
        op4.style.backgroundColor = "lightskyblue";
        selected = op1.value;
    })

    // Show selection for op2
    op2.addEventListener("click", () => {
        op1.style.backgroundColor = "lightskyblue";
        op2.style.backgroundColor = "lightgoldenrodyellow";
        op3.style.backgroundColor = "lightskyblue";
        op4.style.backgroundColor = "lightskyblue";
        selected = op2.value;
    })

    // Show selection for op3
    op3.addEventListener("click", () => {
        op1.style.backgroundColor = "lightskyblue";
        op2.style.backgroundColor = "lightskyblue";
        op3.style.backgroundColor = "lightgoldenrodyellow";
        op4.style.backgroundColor = "lightskyblue";
        selected = op3.value;
    })

    // Show selection for op4
    op4.addEventListener("click", () => {
        op1.style.backgroundColor = "lightskyblue";
        op2.style.backgroundColor = "lightskyblue";
        op3.style.backgroundColor = "lightskyblue";
        op4.style.backgroundColor = "lightgoldenrodyellow";
        selected = op4.value;
    })

    // Grabbing the evaluate button
    const evaluate = document.getElementsByClassName("evaluate");

  
    // Evaluate method
    evaluate[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (selected == "true") {
      // If user was wrong on the first attempt, then they cannot gain points from trying again.
      if (attempts == 0) {
        score = score + 1;
      }
            alert("Correct! Your score is: " + score);
            result[0].style.color = "green";
        } else {
            alert("Incorrect. Your score is: " + score);
            result[0].style.color = "red";
      attempts = attempts + 1;
        }
    })
}

if (start) {
    iterate("0");
}

// Next button and method
const next = document.getElementsByClassName('next')[0];
var id = 0;

next.addEventListener("click", () => {
  attempts = 0
    start = false;
    if (id < 2) {
        id++;
        iterate(id);
        console.log(id);
    }

})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Every time you call `iterate()` you add another event listener to all the other buttons. But you never remove the old event listeners. So clicking the buttons does all the actions from the previous questions.

Comment: Don't add new event listeners each time you start a new question. Add all the event listeners once when the game starts.